# QML: Buttons become transparet over images using Material Style

Tags: qt, qml

I want my application to use an image as a Background. So I use this code:

In my ApplicationWindow:

```
Image {
    id: bkgImage
    source: "qrc:/images/bkg.jpg"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

To add a button

```
Button {
    id: btnAsistencia
    text: qsTr("ASISTENCIA")
    font.pixelSize: fhButttonTextSize
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: btnInscripcion.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: parent.height*0.1
}
```

The code above is for the second button, but I added one before in the exact same way. This is the result:

[image]

The second button becomes transparent over the image. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background colour of the button with the [`Material.background`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-background-attached-prop) attached property:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 440
    visible: true
    color: "red"

    Button {
         text: qsTr("ASISTENCIA")
         Material.background: "#666"
    }
}
```

The default colour has some transparency:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialstyle.cpp#n862